# What controls apport's behavior for saving core dumps?

Tags: crash, apport, proc

apport is configured (default) to handle my system's core dumps (in /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern: `|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P`). It's behavior is mysterious to me:

- Sometimes it saves core dumps in a complete crash dump in /var/crash
- Sometimes it simply saves them in the current working directory
- Sometimes it doesn't save them at all, and I get a message in /var/log/apport.log like:

> this executable already crashed ## times, ignoring

What controls this behavior? Can it be configured? There's no decent man page that I've been able to find.

Comment: Does this link (the wiki) help? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport

Comment: I have read that page several times, but I do not see where it addresses any of the questions I raise above.

Comment: That's fine. I didn't want to read through it to see if it did - I just thought it may help. That's why I commented, rather than answering.

Comment: I really really really wish this could just be answered as well. The features makes perfect sense (DoS protection)... yet is there no way to control it?

Comment: Is there a way to disable this daft behaviour altogether and just get normal, sane, logical, predictable core dump behaviour that's worked for years and that every other distro has, or are ubuntu users forced to use this surreal default settings?